# how to run software installed by root with non-root user

Tags: permissions, centos

I have a few software installed as root (on CentOS 6.9) , and would like to give permission to another user (say **user1**) to run these software.

Just to be clear, the non-root user, **user1** does not see the folders where the software is installed.

How can I do that?

Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm really new to linux. There were of course some discussions on similar matters on the internet, but nothing seems to give a clear guide as how to proceed.

Comment: No, no particular reason

Comment: Then just chmod the directory of the software to 0755 so everyone sees it.

Comment: I do chmod 0755 my_folder  as root user, but still get ``permission denied'' when I try to access by cd to that forlder by user1.  Should I specify to which user I give access to ?

Comment: On CentOS `chmod` alone may not be enough. You might also have to deal with [SE Linux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).

Comment: thanks for all the replies. I was not able to resolve the initial question I had, unfortunately. What I did instead, was removing the software I installed as root (which was in usr/local), and re-installed in /opt directory (still as root), the difference being that opt is visible by other users. It's pretty crude of course but gives at least some solution to the situation.